# How do you use a reactive parameter within a Shiny module?

Tags: r, module, shiny

I have a shiny dashboard page with several graphs that I would like to share a common date selector, but put the graphs into separate modules.

I understand that when I use `callModule` that I need to pass along the object using reactive per

> If a module needs to access an input that isn’t part of the module, the containing app should pass the input value wrapped in a reactive expression (i.e. reactive(...)):
>
> `callModule(myModule, "myModule1", reactive(input$checkbox1))`

but, I don't understand what to do on the other side.

in ui:

```
graphRoFCUI("RoFCNameSpace"),
dateRangeInput("dateRange", "Select Date Range:"
                             , start = max("2016-6-27", Sys.Date()-366)
                             , end = Sys.Date()
                             , min = "2016-6-27"
                             , max = Sys.Date()
            )
```

in server:

`callModule(graphRoFC, id = "RoFCNameSpace", conn, reactive(input$dateRange))`

In my module.R:

```
graphRoFCUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  plotlyOutput(outputId = ns("RoFCOverTime"))
}

...
graphRoFC <- function(input, output, session, conn, dateRange) {
  limitDateRangePercentRoFCDF <- reactive({
    PercentRoFCDF.dateLimited <- subset(PercentRoFCDF, TicketLocalCreatedDate > dateRange[1] & TicketLocalCreatedDate < dateRange[2])
    return(PercentRoFCDF.dateLimited)
  })

...
}
```

What I get is:

```
Warning: Error in $: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
Stack trace (innermost first):
    80: as.Date
    79: ggplotly [sdesc.R#43]
    78: func
    77: origRenderFunc
    76: output$RoFCNameSpace-RoFCOverTime
     1: runApp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to say for sure without looking at the full reproducible code. But whenever you have an error `object of type 'closure' is not subsettable` it almost always means you have a reactive object for which you've failed to use `()`. My guess is that you need to change this line:

`PercentRoFCDF.dateLimited <- subset(PercentRoFCDF, TicketLocalCreatedDate > dateRange[1] & TicketLocalCreatedDate < dateRange[2])`

to 

`PercentRoFCDF.dateLimited <- subset(PercentRoFCDF, TicketLocalCreatedDate > dateRange()[1] & TicketLocalCreatedDate < dateRange()[2])`

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much!